# Find my friends inaccurate location

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Is it possible for find my friends location to initially identify the correct location and then suddenly shift to an inaccurate location even if that person is still in his initial location?

What happened was I was tracking my son on his way to school just to know if he got there safe and after a few minutes, FMF located him exactly where he should be (school), but after checking again, his location changed to a few streets away from where he should be. I tried to find out what that place was and it was a furniture store which is not even open yet.

So I'm wondering if it's possible for find my location to give off inaccurate information?

Comment: It is possible that it will report inaccurate location information. Did it have a light blue area (circle) around the location icon?

Comment: Is it possible your son had since connected to the schools WiFi network?

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's very inaccurate sometimes, believe me I got mad at my daughter because she told me she was at my sisters house but the gps was saying otherwise so I got upset at her but she was actually at her house.My sister confirm that, I had to apologize!

Comment: "the gps was saying otherwise" - it probably wasn't the GPS. If your daughter had connected to your sisters WiFi/broadband connection then the location may now be determined by a GeoIP lookup on your sisters external IP address. This can be extraordinarily inaccurate.